# Displaying png images in an ASP.NET ImageButton control in native size

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I made an ASP.NET web app with an Image control where I display a picture. In the screenshot I attached below you can see that the displayed picture is larger than the container. The container in this case is a panel a wrapped around the Image control. I want to display the picture with an ImageButton control instead. The ImageButton control is supposed to stay a uniform size, even if the pictures are larger in native size than the ImageButton. In the case that the picture is larger, I want scrolbars to appear just like in the screenshot. Can this be done with an ImageButton?

[image: My ASP.NET web forms app]

Comment: Yes, fiddle with some css. It was `div > img` and with a LinkButton it is `div > a > img`

Comment: would I write div > img in the css for ImageButton directly, or as as the argument for an if statement